# Maximum likelihood in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am new both to R and statistics. I am playing with maximum likelihood estimation, and I am getting some incorrect results. I want to model x with a simple linear function:

```
x<-apply(matrix(seq(1,10,1), nrow=1), 1, function(x) 10*x+runif(10,-3,3))
LL<-function(a,b){
    R=apply(x,1,function(y) a*y+b)
    -sum(log(R))
    }
mle(LL, start=list(a=10, b=0))
```

I am getting the following result:

```
Coefficients:
    a         b 
43571.957  1338.345
```

instead of a~10, b~0.

I modified the code according to the suggestions of Spacedman:

```
set.seed(99)
x<-apply(matrix(seq(1,10,1), nrow=1), 1, function(x) 10*x+runif(10,-3,3))
LL<-function(a,b){
R = x[,1] - a*(1:10) + b
-sum(R^2)
}
library(stats4)
mle(LL, start=list(a=11, b=0.3))

Error in solve.default(oout$hessian) : 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
```

I do not know how to get rid of this error. Changing the sees and generating the x values again does not help.

Comment: What package has the `mle` function come from? Also, use `set.seed(99)` before generating your data so we can all use the same random numbers

Comment: @Spacedman mle is from package stats4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of things to notice here. To clarify we start by changing the distribution of the error-term from a uniform distribution `runif(x, -3, 3)` to  the std. normal distribution: `rnorm(x)`. We can now easily simulate your data, then set up your (minus) loglikelihood and maximize (minizime) by:

```
a <- 10 
b <- 0
set.seed(99)
x <- apply(matrix(seq(1, 10, 1), nrow=1), 1, function(x) b + a * x + rnorm(10))
minuslogL <- function(a, b) -sum(dnorm(x[, 1] - (b + a * 1:10), log = TRUE))
library(stats4)
mle(minuslogL, start = list(a = 11, b = 0.3))

Call:
mle(minuslogl = minuslogL, start = list(a = 11, b = 0.3))

Coefficients:
        a         b 
9.8732793 0.5922192
```

Notice that this works well, since the likelihood is smooth and `mle()` uses "BFGS" for the optimization, eg. a quasi-Newton, gradient approach. Lets try the same with uniform errors:

```
set.seed(99)
x <- apply(matrix(seq(1, 10, 1), nrow=1), 1, function(x) b + a * x + runif(10, -3, 3))
minuslogL2 <- function(a,b) -sum(dunif(x[, 1] -(a * 1:10 + b), -3, 3, log = TRUE))
mle(minuslogL2, start = list(a = 11, b = 0.3))

Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

This fails! Why? Since the uniform-errors restrict the parameter space, you will not get a smooth likelihood. If you move your parameters a,b too far away from the true values, you will get Inf. If you move close enough, you will get the same likelihood (eg. many possible min. values):

```
> minuslogL2(11, 0.3)
[1] Inf
> minuslogL2(10, 0)
[1] 17.91759
> minuslogL2(10.02, 0.06)
[1] 17.91759
```

Maximizing this likelihood compares to finding the set: `{a,b}: -logL(a, b) == -logL(10, 0)`, which can be found by a plain search algorithm.

Comment: Thank you J.R. I thought that during maximum likelihood estimation we are maximising the distribution function which produces the data. Are you maximising here the errors' distribution function? Do you know any book which treats this topic on an intuitive level?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes I'm maximizing the errors distribution, but this is the exact same. In the normal case, with y=b+ax+e e~N(0,1), it corresponds to: `dnorm(y,a*x+b,1)` or `dnorm(y-ax-b,0,1)`. There are millions of introductory statistics books containing MLE. Pick one in your own area of research or try "Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 7th Edition"